# Reset timer when it reaches zero value

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I found many examples of how to reset timer, but they usually concerned **manual reset** (e.g. on-click button event).

I need a logic that will **automatically** reset the value when the countdown ends.

### Timer:

```
type seconds = number;
const getRemainingTime$ = (store: Store): Observable<seconds> => {
  // calculate fullTime based on the TriggerDate extracted from the State
  // ...
  return fullTime$.pipe(
    switchMap((fullTime: seconds) =>
      timer(0, 1000).pipe(
        map((tickCount: number) => fullTime - tickCount),
        takeWhile((remainingTime: seconds) => remainingTime >= 0)
      )
    )
  );
}
```

### Trigger (wait for `0` value on timer)

```
getRemainingTime$(this.store).pipe(
    skipWhile((remainingTime: seconds) => remainingTime > 0),
)
.subscribe(data => {
    const newTriggerDate: Date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 1000);  // +60 seconds
    this.store.dispatch([new SetTriggerDateAction({ newTriggerDate })]);
});
```

**...and it doesn't work** -

When the remaining time is zero, the trigger goes crazy and dispatch an infinite number of actions. What is wrong?

PS: When I manually dispatch SetTriggerDateAction (onClick button), the problem disappears.

Comment: Since you're using `takeWhile` that will complete the chain you can add [`repeat()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/repeat) that will automatically resubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

It was enough to replace `skipWhile` to a `filter`.

### skipWhile

**All values** are emitted if the condition in skipWhile is met at least once.

---

### filter

**Only those values** specified in the condition are emitted.